# Flush grid layout of buttons in .Net for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I have a grid of objects that I am generating programmatically.

For testing purposes, each cell in the grid is a Border object whose child is an Image object.  Each cell is placed flush against it's neighbor and displays perfectly.

When I replace each Image object with a Button object (each cell is still a Border object, just with a Button for its child rather than an Image), a noticeable gap appears between cells.

I have tried setting margin, padding, et al to 0.

What is unique about Buttons that makes them behave this way, and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Margin` is defined in the control template. you can change it by following these steps:

Right click on a button in the designer and select `Edit Template` > `Edit a Copy...` from the context menu.

[image: Context menu]

In the dialog select the name for the new style and choose where you want to put it.

[image: Create style dialog]

Now find the following block of XAML in the style and set `Margin` to `0`.

```
<Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Border>
```

Assign the new style to all your buttons by either removing `x:Key` from the style declaration:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <!-- style definition -->
</Style>
```

Or by setting the style to selected buttons:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
```

Either way, you'll have your buttons next to each other without any gap between them.

Comment: Thanks, what was throwing me off was the embedded border having a margin of 3, instead of the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not strictly speaking familiar with how windows store apps work, but I don't imagine it's too far from general WPF / Silverlight. I get the same frustration from label controls with unnecessary padding when placed side by side. What you can do is just use negative-margin and that will correct it. I think it's totally not clean that you have to do that, but it does work.